# Need to run Rails 2.2.2 but I have RubyGems 1.3.6 it wants 1.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

I have a Rails program that has 2.2.2 embedded.  When I run it I get an error because RubyGems 1.3.6 is not compatible with Rails 2.2.2. I am running rvm and would like to set up an environment to run this program with ruby 1.8.7 and rubygems 1.3.5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Barb

Answer (score 2):

To install rubygems 1.3.5 run this : gem install rubygems-update -v 1.3.5
or try to use RVM ( this way you won't break existing code that requires version > 1.3.5 of rubygems ).